# AFNetworking 2.0 "_NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown" linking error on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using

- AFNetworking 2.0
- Mac OS X 10.8.0
- Xcode 5

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown", referenced from:
      -[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:] in AFURLSessionManager-C493EEE75215474B.o
      -[AFURLSessionManager uploadTaskWithTask:progress:completionHandler:] in AFURLSessionManager-C493EEE75215474B.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
```

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 in an Mac OS X project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mac OS 10.8, the error seems plausible, because `NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown` (and `NSURLSession` and `AFURLSessionManager`) requires Mac OS 10.9 or iOS 7.0 and later.

There was a rendition of AFNetworking 2.0 that was not correctly checking the OS version and trying to include `AFURLSessionManager` even when using targets prior to 10.9 and iOS 7.0. This has since been remedied, and this particular problem should go away if you update your [AFNetworking 2.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) code to the latest version.

Comment: I haven't got this issue until I install AFNetworking library using cocoapods. It seems that it installed 2.1 version but it crashes because of this error. I dont know why.

Comment: BTW, It crashes on iOS 6.1 SDK.

Comment: it crashes on macosx 10.8 too

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following frameworks:

```
SystemConfiguration
Security
CFNetwork
```

Comment: Yep, this solves the typical AFNetworking linking errors. Or, if using Xcode 5.0, you can turn on the "Enable Modules" setting under "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - Module settings", and the needed frameworks are added automatically. I don't think the missing frameworks is the issue here, but you're right that the failure to include the necessary frameworks can cause all sorts of annoying linking errors.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who crashes on ios **6 sdk** and using **cocoapods** check on your pod file.
platform :ios, '6.0' needs to be 6 not 7

Solved the problem for me.