# dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown AFNetworking 2.1.0

Tags: ios, macos, xcode5, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I installed the latest version 2.1.0 of AFNetworking with Cocoa pods. When I run the app on the 6.1 simulator I get the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
  Referenced from: /Users/OskarLarsson/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/7F665584-0657-4E3E-A416-87C018E6964C/xxxx.app/xxxxx
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 in /Users/OskarLarsson/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/7F665584-0657-4E3E-A416-87C018E6964C/xxxx.app/xxxx
(lldb)
```

I found a similar question [AFNetworking 2.0 "_NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown" linking error on Mac OS X 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225976/afnetworking-2-0-nsurlsessiontransfersizeunknown-linking-error-on-mac-os-x-10), that had been answered but since my app still crashes on this version of AFNetworking and ond iOS 6.1 I wonder if anybody knows what I'm doing wrong or if I'm forgetting something.

I'm using: AFNetworking 2.1.0, Mac OS X 10.9.1 and Xcode 5

Answer (score 6):

AFNetworking 2.0 requires iOS 7. NSURLSession class is unavailable in iOS 6 because it is iOS 7 feature

Comment: So if I want to support iOS 6.1 and iOS 7 with AFNetworking I can't use AFNetworking 2.1.0?